# SQLite not working on real Device - Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Xamarin.ios not inserting data in table on real device but working properly on simulator. I've set sqlite DB file build action property to 'Bundle Resource' but still not working. Getting data from a DB is working properly on Both simulator and on real device.

```
if (_person == null)
{
var a = conn.Execute("insert into Person(Id,Name,Gender) values(?,?,?,?,?)", _person.Id, _person.Name, _person.Gender);
}
conn.Commit();
```

Comment: files contained in the app bundle are read-only.  If you want a writable db, you will need to copy it from the bundle to a writable user folder

Comment: thanks, can you refer to any sample code

Comment: http://arteksoftware.com/deploying-a-database-file-with-a-xamarin-forms-app/